# MiniTest: using the seed inside the tests

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is there a way to use the seed given my minitest/autorun inside test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing: [Kernel::srand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-srand).

```
seed = srand  # set a new seed and return the current one
srand(seed)   # restore it
```